# Heroku H10 deployment error code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm keeping on getting error H10 with status code 503, saying my app crashed, together with the next err msgs: (below is the *full* err msg from my Heroku logs)

Error: Cannot find module './secrets.json'  Require stack: /app/server.js

and

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]

I am not sure I understand what it means by '/app/server.js' ? My server.js file is located in my project's root folder which isn't ‘app'.

I followed all my logs, read all of Heroku's docs and made the required changes in my code as far as i could to the best of my knowledge. Still, I get the same result.

Those are the steps i took so far:

- npm version update
- Node.js version update
- Updated npm/node.js versions in my package.json under 'engines' section.
- npm init command to make sure all of my project's modules are up to date and installed.
- Added Procfile to my project's root folder with the txt: web:npm start /web:node server.js (tried them both together and apart, checked wrong spelling and white spaces).
- Maid sure my port set to: process.env.PORT || 8080
- My db.js : process.env.DATABASE_URL || .  .  .
- heroku restart
- After all the above mentioned changes i pushed the changes to my github, redeployed on Heroku and it failed to succeed.

NOTE: the project is in a cloned github repo which i cloned to my local machine from a remote repo. can the problem be related to that somehow?
 
thanks
 
My logs:

```
I'm keeping on getting error H10 with status code 503, saying my app crashed, together with the next err msgs: (below is the \*full\* err msg from my Heroku logs)

Error: Cannot find module './secrets.json'  Require stack: /app/server.js

and

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: \[ '/app/server.js' \]

I am not sure I understand what it means by '/app/server.js' ? My server.js file is located in my project's root folder which isn't ‘app'. 

I followed all my logs, read all of Heroku's docs and made the required changes in my code as far as i could to the best of my knowledge. Still, I get the same result.

 Those are the steps i took so far:

- npm version update

- Node.js version update

- Updated npm/node.js versions in my package.json under 'engines' section.

- npm init command to make sure all of my project's modules are up to date and installed.

- Added Procfile to my project's root folder with the txt: web:npm start /web:node server.js (tried them both together and apart, checked wrong spelling and white spaces).

- Maid sure my port set to: process.env.PORT || 8080

- My db.js : process.env.DATABASE_URL || .  .  . 

- heroku restart

- After all the above mentioned changes i pushed the changes to my github, redeployed on Heroku and it failed to succeed.

NOTE: the project is in a cloned github repo which i cloned to my local machine from a remote repo. can the problem be related to that somehow? 
 
thanks
 
My logs:

2023-07-01T19:42:53.159323+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-07-01T19:42:56.049904+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2023-07-01T19:42:57.825975+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-07-01T19:42:57.826010+00:00 app[web.1]: > petition@1.0.0 start
2023-07-01T19:42:57.826010+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2023-07-01T19:42:57.826011+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037800+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037802+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw err;
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037802+00:00 app[web.1]:   ^
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037803+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037803+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './secrets.json'
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037803+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037804+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037804+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037805+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037805+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037805+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037805+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:15:34)
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037806+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037806+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037806+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037807+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037807+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037807+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037808+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037808+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037812+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-07-01T19:42:58.037812+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v18.16.1
2023-07-01T19:42:58.238635+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2023-07-01T19:42:58.267875+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: Something is looking for a file `/app/server.js` which isn't there. Could you provide us with some code to debug further?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.